# python script while using python3.5 in cmd

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I run this code:

```
# initialize data to be stored in files 
# records 
bob = {'name':'Bob Smith', 'age': 42, 'pay': 30000, 'job': 'dev'}

sue = {'name':'Sue Jones', 'age': 45, 'pay': 50000, 'job': 'HR'} 

# database 
db = {} 

db['bob'] = bob 

db['sue'] = sue 

if _name_ == '_main_': # when run as a script     
    for key in db:         
        print(key, '=>\n ', db[key])
```

I keep getting this message:

> ```
> C:\Users\Lenovo Thinkpad\Desktop\manage>py initdata.py 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "initdata.py", line 12, in <module>     if _name_ == '_main_': # when run as a script 
> NameError: name '_name_' is not defined.
> ```

It would be nice if i learnt how to run the code properly

Comment: the line 12 is actually written as: if _name_ == '_main_'

Comment: `if _name_ == '_main_'` --> `if __name__ == '__main__'` (double the underscores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change:- if _name_ == '_main_'
    to   if __name__ == '__main__' 
(double underscores) OR (Dunder)
```

Comment: Thank you very much highly appreciated

Comment: please mark as answer so it will be useful for others